# MySQL: Selecting many rows but establishing a limit on 1

Tags: mysql

I have a table that consists of the following:

```
food  || last_order_date 
-------------------------
pizza || 2011-10-25 19:00 
=========================
pasta || 2011-10-25 23:00 
=========================
pizza || 2011-10-29 15:00 
=========================
pasta || 2011-10-31 18:00 
=========================
```

What I want to achieve is to obtain a table ordered by `last_order_date` for each food. So, the result would be:

```
food  || last_order_date 
-------------------------
pasta || 2011-10-31 18:00 
=========================
pizza || 2011-10-29 15:00 
=========================
```

How can I achieve that? I tried many things but all I obtained were orders from the whole table, instead of each food element. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT   food, 
         MAX(last_order_date) AS max_last_order_date
    FROM table
GROUP BY food
ORDER BY max_last_order_date DESC
```